# Is there different word corresponding to "teatime" in American English?

Tags: american-english, british-english

There is a British English term "teatime" or "afternoon tea". I'm wondering how people refer to it in American English.

Comment: It doesn't really exist in America. If you want to describe the time of day that British people stop work and have tea, we call it teatime, too... or 3 pm.

Comment: Can confirm. People just drink tea for the heck of it. Any time is tea time... ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Are you looking for the pronunciation or for the dictionary entry in the U.S. That corresponds to the British 'teatime'?

Comment: Well, they say "teatime".  But not very often.

Comment: Also, if you're specifically talking about saying it out loud, you'd probably get someone confusing teatime with tee time... your reserved time to begin playing a round of golf.

Comment: @Jimmy, Looks like it will confuse people if I use it. :-) Maybe "3 PM" more reasonable?

Comment: @Mitch I'm not looking for pronunciation. I'm looking for which word American usually use in oral. As Jimmy pointed, Looks like "teatime" also means sex in America. So I guess American usually use "3 PM"? Or some word else?

Comment: @Catija, So "3 PM" is more common and local?

Comment: @Wilber82 Only if you refer specifically to the time "3 pm" as "teatime". 3 pm doesn't mean anything special that 11 pm or 5 am doesn't mean. I was simply trying to emphasize that, as Americans, we don't generally know what "teatime" is outside of a stereotypical concept... I'm not even sure it occurs at 3 pm, to be honest... I just have a vague notion it's in the afternoon... Oh, but I did go to a "high tea" in a fancy hotel once. We had tea and cucumber sandwiches and scones with clotted cream. It was lovely.

Comment: Wilber82: 'teatime' does not mean 'sex' in the US. There might be some extremely narrow slang where there might be some relation, but don't take Urban Dictionary seriously. That is one possible (and very dubious) meaning out of many. As @Catija mentions, if the word is spoken rather than written, it's most likely to be understood as the time when you're going to start a game of golf.

Comment: The fancy tea that Catija had is "afternoon tea". "High tea" is an early evening meal.

Comment: the closest Americans have is "snack time", which is really anytime that one chooses to eat a *snack* (a small informal meal). Snacks are generally eaten between major meals, especially between lunch and dinner. Tea is not often a proponent of American snacks; rather, processed foods (e.g., crackers and cookies) as well as fruits and/or vegetables are more likely to be eaten as a snack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know (as an American who lived, very briefly in England), there is no word in the US for the British concept of "tea", "teatime" or "afternoon tea".

In fact, the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_%28meal%29) on it pretty clearly points out that it's a UK & Ireland concept:

> Tea refers to several different meals in countries formerly part of the British Empire.
>
> - Afternoon Tea
> - High Tea (Meat tea)
> - Evening Meal

Yes, we were part of the "British Empire"... but the "tea" thing didn't stick here.

We have fancy hotels in big cities that are British-themed and sell a canned "high tea", but even our "[high tea](http://www.amny.com/eat-and-drink/high-tea-in-nyc-5-spots-to-raise-your-pinky-1.9502472)" (as defined in this New York article)

> Pinkies up! It's time for high tea.
>
> The leisurely afternoon affair has gained popularity in the past few months in New York City, according to tea authority Kathy Chan.
>
> A proper high tea consists of three things: finger sandwiches, scones and sweets. Many hotels here that offer afternoon tea are revamping services to make the food pairings more interesting and expanding their tea offerings, says Chan.

doesn't fit with the Wikipedia definition of a "high tea":

> High tea (also known as meat tea or tea time in Ireland) usually refers to the evening meal or dinner of the working class, typically eaten between 5 pm and 7 pm.
>
> High tea typically consists of a hot dish, followed by cakes and bread, butter and jam. Occasionally there would be cold cuts of meat, such as ham salad. The term was first used around 1825, and high is used in the sense of well-advanced (like high noon, for example) to signify that it was taken later in the day than afternoon tea; it was used predominantly by the working class and in certain British dialects of the north of England and Scotland.

"High Tea" in the US, at a hotel or similar establishment, generally occurs in the mid-afternoon 1 pm - 4 pm time frame and consists of tea, finger sandwiches, and sweet cakes. The hotels usually get the terminology right and call it "afternoon tea" but if you search "high tea New York", you get results for the same establishments.

Here's one in DC, at [The Willard InterContinental](http://washington.intercontinental.com/food-drink/peacock-alley-tea):

> The best afternoon tea in Washington, DC
>
> For a taste of the finer things, The Willard InterContinental proudly hosts afternoon tea in Peacock Alley. This enchanting restaurant features live harp music, an array of organic teas, finger sandwiches and fresh decadent pastries in an elegant setting. One of the city’s more unique traditions for over a century, afternoon tea at The Willard is a not-to-be-missed experience.

Americans do not generally have a meal between lunch (noon meal) and dinner or supper (evening meal). We may have an afternoon snack but that usually involves finding a bag of chips (British crisps) or candy bar from the vending machine or a leftover doughnut from the break room and grabbing your 4th (or 10th) cup of coffee for the day.

We're very uncivilized.

---

So, what should you say? That depends on what you're trying to tell someone, which you haven't explained in your question.

I'd start by saying "teatime" or "afternoon tea" and be prepared to explain it a little if they ask. It's a foreign concept to  a lot of us.